# How to change Bootstrap accordion button title when collapsed (using CSS)

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am struggling to change a Bootstrap accordion button so that, when collapsed, it should say "See Less -". I am fairly sure I'm meant to use the css property *content* but can't for the life of me figure out where. My html looks like this:

```
    <h2>Some Heading</h2>
    <div style="display:table; margin:auto;">
       <ul style="margin-bottom: 0">
          <li class="services-list">Item 1</li>
          <li class="services-list">Item 2</li>
          <li class="services-list">Item 3</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
       <div id="collapse-custom" class="collapse">
          <div class="card card-block">
             <div style="display:table; margin:auto; width: 49%;">
                <ul>
                   <li class="services-list">Item 4</li>
                   <li class="services-list">Item 5</li>
                   <li class="services-list">Item 6</li>
                   <li class="services-list">Item 7</li>
                   <li class="services-list">Item 8</li>
                </ul>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-target="#collapse-custom">See More<i class="fa fa-plus" 
    style="padding-left: 10px;"></i>
</button>
```

Any help would be very gratefully received!. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Give your button a class say btn-toggle:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-target="#collapse-custom">See More<i class="fa fa-plus" 
    style="padding-left: 10px;"></i>
```

Then, If you can use jquery the code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
             $(".btn-toggle").click(function () {
                    if($(".btn-toggle").text()=="See More"){
                        $(".btn-toggle").text("See Less -");
                    }
                    else {
                        $(".btn-toggle").text("See More +");
                    }
                });
          });       
</script>
```

Hope it will work

Comment: Crisp & simple solution to handle!

Answer (score 1):

A more Bootstrap-friendly way of doing it:

1. Give the button an ID:

`<button id="btn-service-list" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-custom">See More<i class="fa fa-plus" style="padding-left: 10px;"></i>`

2. This JS into your .js file or inside a  tag on the same page:

```js
$('#collapse-custom').on('shown.bs.collapse',function(){
    $('#btn-service-list').text('- Show less');
});
$('#collapse-custom').on('hidden.bs.collapse',function(){
    $('#btn-service-list').text('+ Show more');
});
```